# pyinstaller squares instead of letters

Tags: wxpython, pyinstaller

I've tried to pack my wxpython application with pyinstaller. At the moment I succeeded to pack and start it on another computer, but all the text are just squares. Does anyone has an idea what wrong and how to solve it.

I packed it on a Debian wheezy 32-bit, and had tested it on Debian squeeze 32-bit and Debian Jessie 64-bit. (Both had this square problem).

When i try to launch the program I get the warnings below

Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 70: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig error: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 70: non-double matrix element
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf", line 78: saw unknown, expected number

(main:27557): Pango-CRITICAL **: No modules found:
No builtin or dynamically loaded modules were found.
PangoFc will not work correctly.
This probably means there was an error in the creation of:
  '/etc/pango/pango.modules'
You should create this file by running:
  pango-querymodules > '/etc/pango/pango.modules'

(main:27557): Pango-WARNING **: failed to choose a font, expect ugly output. engine-type='PangoRenderFc', script='latin'

(main:27557): Pango-WARNING **: failed to choose a font, expect ugly output. engine-type='PangoRenderFc', script='common'

Comment: Are you using a custom font? Does the text fit the buttons?

Comment: Hi, yes I use the standard system font and the squares fits fine the buttons

Comment: I forget to mention that I am also using matplotlib for some plotting and here is the text fine.

Comment: Which wxPython and Python versions?

Comment: Python is 2.7.3 and wxpython is 2.8.12

Comment: I found the problem, it seems that the packed libpango.so was the problem. I removed it and afterwards it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some encoding issue?  What are our Python modules encoded in?  ASCII or UTF-8?

With py2exe I need to use this hack in my app module:

1. people say one should leave this alone and use decode/encode, or define this in sitecustomize.py
2. either of them don't really work for me, so as long as the following does
3. this is what I will do until I switch to Py 3.x

-

```
if hasattr(sys, "frozen"):  #Py2Exe does not run Site.py
    sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
    del sys.setdefaultencoding
else:
    #The Python interpreter needs to reload the function
    # save/restore the excepthook, otherwise WingIDE won't see some exceptions
    hook = sys.excepthook
    reload(sys)
    sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
    del sys.setdefaultencoding
    sys.excepthook = hook
```